# How to support multiple browser tabs on Blazor Server app in Windows 10 IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I published my Blazor server app to my local IIS on Windows 10. It works well, but I am no able to open more than one window/tab of the website. If I try, it loads forever until I close my former app window.

Is this behavior due to SignalR on Windows 10 being limited? Or am I missing something?
Other than that, the app compiles and works as expected.

The application pool is on No Managed Code, Integrated. IIS 10.

**Update**

This does not happen with IIS Express, only on local IIS.

Appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "env": "dev",
  "connStrDev": "my dev conn",
  "connStrTest": "my test conn",
  "BaseUrl": "http://localhost/MyProjectName/"
}
```

App.Razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Domain.Models.Static 
<head>

</head>
<div class="sidebar col-lg-3 " >
    <div class="logo">TeamApp Manager</div>
    <hr style="background-color:white;" />
    <UserList/>
</div>

<div class="main" dir="ltr">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <HeadMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">

        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

This should be working like any normal IIS web app. Any ideas? Again, the code itself runs fine on local IIS but would not start on a 2nd browser tab or window.

Desired Behavior: App working correctly on local IIS.

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the code.

Comment: a) do multiple tabs work on IIS Express or Kestrel?  b) show you config code.

Comment: I updated the original post. It works fine on IIS Express (with multiple tabs open)

Comment: I got the exact same issue. It is quite hard to debug because on iis express it just works fine. Only when i deploy to IIS the issue appears. Have you been able to fix this issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to fix it and eventually modified my project to Blazor WebAssembly. (Its a rather small project so was doable).

Comment: Just trying to help, but the main cause can be that blazor web assembly does not support multithread, in net7 multithreading is comming

Comment: @hesolar The topic is about Blazor server, not Blazor Webassembly. It is a known limitation of IIS (not IIS Express) on non server Windows operating systems (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions), because on Blazor server each tab has a persistent SignalR connection, so when in IIS is reached the maximum of 10 contemporary connections the 11th hangs.. The solution is to use "IIS Express" during development (instead of IIS) or use a Window server operating system.