# IIS can only support three instances of a Blazor server client?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I've download Visual Studio 2022 and tested the default Blazor Server template *(Home/Counter/FetchData)*. In Visual Studio, IIS Express I can open as many tabs / instances of the application as I want.

When I host the default Blazor Server template in local IIS (**Windows 10 Home 21H2**, IIS 10) I can only open three instance of the application. The fourth will hang until the first is closed. I see someone has ran into [nearly the exact same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998274/how-to-support-multiple-browser-tabs-on-blazor-server-app-in-windows-10-iis) but there is no solution provided.

Anyone know whats going on? I don't understand why IIS Express can handle multiple instnaces but IIS 10 can not. Even [Conveyor by Keyoti](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) can support many many tabs compared to IIS 10.

Note: I notice SignalR has [limitations on Windows / IIS of 10 concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iis-limitations-on-windows-client-os) connections, but I'm not even getting two.

**Updates**

- Out of curiosity I tested it on Windows Server 2016 Standard and I can open hundreds of tabs.
- I re-installed IIS on Windows 10 to make sure something wasn't wacky.
- I've ensured `WebSocket` Protocol is enabled.

Comment: This probably doesn't help, but I can't repro this. This works fine in IIS for me.

Comment: @AdamVincent Hey Adam thanks for the response. Can you let me know your OS/IIS versions? Also, are the tabs actually functionable?

Comment: It also works fine in my side. `Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2, OS Build 19044.1766, IIS Version 10.0.19041.1`.

Comment: IIS on Windows HOME has some restrictions. This is probably one of them. You need at least Windows Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 Home supports 3 concurrent connections at the same time, [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions).

Normal HTTP requests to IIS get process and response returned. So even if you manage to achieve 4 or more at the same time, IIS will work through the request queue and you may not have noticed that your request was slightly delayed unless your individual requests take a while to process.

However with SignalR, a persistent connection is maintained to the server. So if you open one connection per browser tab, and you have 4 tabs open, that 4th tab is going to hang indefinitely until one of the other page has its connection ended (by closing the tab, manually disconnecting via code, or refreshing the page).

Comment: I updated my answer to include a solution, do you see problems with that?

Comment: @clamchoda Yes, don't edit solutions into your question. Use a separate answer post for that.

Comment: My apologies I have changed to an answer as request, but now my answer has a question ha

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue, and I have tried to search some way to solve it.I will summarize a few ways below that you can try.

1. Try to install `Websocket Protocol` in your Win10. You can find it in Windows features.

   [image]
2. Workaround: install `IIS Express` in [Web Platform Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview#installing-iis-express).
3. Workaround: Try to deploy it in windows server, and check whether have same issue. I found some posts also mentioned it may related with OS version.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason. I have done option 1.) and option 3.) does solve the issue but I was hoping to save my client some money. When I try option 2.) it always says I have a more recent version than the Web Platform Installer. I noticed you have Windows Enterprise, I wonder if its a restriction of my Windows Home.

Comment: @clamchoda You are right. Win 10 Home connection limit is 3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions

Comment: @mason Thanks so much. I was ripping my hair out trying to find that information. I kept finding a restriction of 10 which didn't make sense for my scenario.

Comment: @Jason Pan I updated my answer to include a solution, do you see problems with that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was incredibly simple (maybe too simple?). Don't use IIS at all.

- In `Program.cs` just before building the app I override Kestrel ports to listen on any ip (for now).
- *(Optional)* I provide a custom SSL certificate in the `UseHttps` constructor so that it can be emailed and installed on iOS and Android devices.
- *(Required)* Then I publish the applications to a folder and just run the `.exe` on the hosting machines.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.ListenAnyIP(8000);
    opt.ListenAnyIP(8001, listOpt =>
    {
        listOpt.UseHttps(@"Path to.pfx file", "password for pfx file");
    });
});
```

Now Windows 10 Home can support as many connections as the hardware can handle at `https://192.168.0.XXX:8001`. Is this how Blazor Server is expected to be deployed within a local network? I don't understand how this overcomes the [connection limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions) pointed out in [masons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72982386/591285). Please let me know in the comments if I'm missing something.

Comment: The connection limit is on IIS - it's intended by Microsoft to keep companies from using Win 10 Home as a server in production. They want you to shell out the money for a full blown Windows Server license for production use. The connection limit is not present on Kestrel, which is why it overcomes the limitation. Generally Blazor Server when deployed on Windows would be hosted in IIS because of the security benefits that IIS provides. On Linux, you'd probably put Nginx or some other proxy that provides equivalent security.

Comment: @mason Thanks a lot for taking the time to address everything. You've really helped me understand my problem in its entirety.